# How to notify the parent dialog of a button down message

Tags: c++, mfc, subclassing

I want to subclass a CButton to handle the ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN message.

DownButton.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include "DownButton.h" 

//CDownButton 

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CDownButton, CButton) 

CDownButton::CDownButton() 
{ 
} 

CDownButton::~CDownButton() 
{ 
} 


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CDownButton, CButton) 
    ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN() 
END_MESSAGE_MAP() 



// CDownButton message handlers 

void CDownButton::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point) 
{ 
}
```

DownButton.h

```
#pragma once 


// CDownButton 

class CDownButton : public CButton 
{ 
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CDownButton) 

public: 
    CDownButton(); 
    virtual ~CDownButton(); 

protected: 
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP() 
public: 
    afx_msg void OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point); 
};
```

But how can the dialog containing this button be notified of this happening ? It seems the only message it can receive is ON_BN_CLICKED.

Comment: I have not used MFC for years, but I think that the parent window could directly receive notifications for event in its childs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-send the message to the parent in your OnLButtonDown - Event:

```
void CDownButton::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point) 
{ 
   // do what you want to do ...

   GetParent()->SendMessage(WM_COMMAND, GetDlgCtrlID() | WM_LBUTTONDOWN << 16, (LONG) GetSafeHwnd());
}
```

Comment: I get that I should add `ON_COMMAND(ID_BUTTON, &Dialog::function)` in the `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP` of the dialog, but how would the WM_LBUTTONDOWN be used ?